Using same Google Play Integrity encryption key for more than 1 App
I'm managing more than 1 App, also managing locally the GPI integrity result and I would like to know if is possible to have the the same Google Play Integrity encryption key for all the Apps.
It will help me to not manage different Apps ID and several keys to validate the verdict on my backend.
Best Regards,
Rubén.
I can export the encryption key per App but I don't know if I could import my keys to GPI service.
